# Content Provider not visible from outside the app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

need some help with my content provider.

I created a Content Provider following official docs, which will expose some data to my other apps.

The problem is that I cannot see the Content Provider outside the app that implement the Content Provider. When testing in the same app, is working as expected, but not from other apps.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CESAppStore"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">

.
.
.
 <provider
            android:name=".provider.CesAppContentProvider"
            android:authorities="authority_string"
            android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Im using this code to get all available Content Providers and my content provider is not displayed.

```
for (pack in context.packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS)) {
            val providers = pack.providers
            if (providers != null) {
                for (provider in providers) {
                    Timber.d("Example provider: ${provider.authority}")
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried a bunch of different options inside the provider tag but nothing seems to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you using an Android 11 device?

Comment: Yes, emulator Pixel 3, Android R

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for the suggestion, now is working, do you know how can I solve this problem for Android R. having a Content Provider and not been able to use it on lattes Android phones is not very usefully.

Comment: It has to do with package visibility. You have to add a queries tag in your manifest for that package or add a query all packages permission.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps you point me in the correct direction.